# A difficult mix between thermodynamics and electricity

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity

Consider the device in the image.The cylinder has dielectric walls which do not permit heat change between the gas that is inside and the exterior environment.The cap A of the cylinder and the piston P are metallic and united by a flexible metallic wire which also ties up a continuous current source,a resistor and a switch.Initially,the piston is in balance.At closure, through a random procedure of the switch K,the condenser formed by the piston and the cylinder's cap is charged by the source and its armatures attract each other,tending to compress the gas.The heat emitted by the resistor during the charge of the condenser heats the gas which tends to relax.What will happen when the swtich is closed : will the gas be compressed or will it relax?
[image]

Based on my intuition, I believe that the gas relaxes,but I haven't made any progress on proving this.

Comment: Why does the gas necessarily have to either expand (or compress)? Why can't the dividing line between expansion or compression be determined by the circuit components, the geometry, and the materials?

Comment: Did you mean to write current source?

Comment: @Chemomechanics I think that if there are more cases then the problem wants us to consider them separately

Comment: Then I suppose you'd want to start by formulating the force of electrostatic attraction and the energy dissipation associated with resistive heating.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I tried to use Coulomb's Law,but I don't know what to do afterwards. Could you show me how to solve this ?